# Grow lights for indoor houseplants in a low-light living room

Tags: indoors, light, grow-lamp, led

I have several houseplants situated on shelves in my ground-floor living room. The light from the window is quite diffuse and doesn’t reach them well. Considering winter and generally bad weather, this side of the room is dark, and they hardly receive any light at all.

I’m considering setting up grow lights to supplement their light needs, but I’m overwhelmed with the options available and need some guidance:

1. **Light quality & effectiveness:** How do I determine the right kind of grow lights for common houseplants? There are many products on Amazon, but their descriptions are often vague. I want to ensure I’m not purchasing simple LED lights without the necessary spectrum for plant growth.
2. **Price point:** I’ve noticed a wide range of prices for grow lights. What’s a reasonable price range for effective lights? I want to avoid scams or overpriced products that don’t deliver.
3. **LED strips:** I’m interested in LED strips that could fit within the under and remain inconspicuous when turned off. Is this a viable solution for my plants? I’m concerned about compromising effectiveness for aesthetics due to the low surface area.

Any advice or product recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Are you committed to this particular arrangement? It's going to be moderately inefficient to light, and will require ceiling or wall mounted lights for the plants on the top shelf.

Comment: I’m definitely torn, but I’d say I like the idea of having plants there more than a dead-looking shelf.